# discord.py: Sending invite through user DMs

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

So I wrote this command which I thought would send an invite to the member that was tagged but apparently I am missing something.

It returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 902, in invoke
     await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 864, in invoke
     await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
     raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Invite' object has no attribute 'ctx'
```

Thanks.

```
import discord
from discord.ext    import commands

class Invite(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def invite(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *argument):
        link = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_uses=1, unique=True)
        await member.send(link)
        await ctx.send(f'{member.name} has received an invite.')
 

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Invite(client))
```

Comment: What exactly is your question. Does it not do what its supposed to do? Is it throwing an error? Please elaborate.

Comment: I have edited my question, sorry for being unclear

Comment: Please include the full traceback

Comment: @mousetail Is this okay or would you like me to run it from my own computer and post the full traceback since it runs on Heroku?

Comment: This doesn't look like the full traceback, try running `heroku logs -n 1500` to get the entire thing, or try to invoke the command and get the full traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have to request the invite in another way.

**Try out the following:**

```py
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def invite(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, total: int = None):
    guild = self.client.get_channel(ctx.channel.id)
    link = await guild.create_invite(max_uses=1 if total is not None else total, unique=True)
    await member.send(link)
    await ctx.send(f'{member.name} has received an invite.')
```

**What did we do?**

- Get the `channel.id` and define it as `guild`
- Create an invite to `guild` with max. 1 use and the property of being `unique`
- Send the `link` to the member and confirm it by bot

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry for responding late. This solved the problem, thanks again.